# Probability distribution: finding 'a'

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider the random variable X with probability distribution,

$$
P(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2/a & -2,-1,0,1,2 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

---

a) Find $a$ and $E(X)$.

b) What is the probability distribution of random variable $Z = (X - E[X])^2$?

c) Using part b), compute the variance of $X$.

---

I think I understand parts b, c, and the second part of a, but I'm not sure how to find $a$. Maybe there's a formula I'm missing?

---

a) a = 10, E(X) = 0

b) $$P(Z = z) = 
 \begin{cases} 
      0 & z = 0 \\
      \frac{2}{10} & z = 1 \\
      \frac{8}{10} & z = 2 
  \end{cases}$$

alt. b) $$P(Z = z) = 
 \begin{cases} 
      \frac{2}{5} & z = 1 \\
      \frac{4}{5} & z = 4 \\
      0 & otherwise
  \end{cases}$$

Comment: You might find [the meta thread on how to use MathJax/LaTeX useful](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5025/437127).

Answer (score 2):

We know that the sum of all the probabilities has to be $1$. Therefore:

$$\frac{(-2)^2}{a}+\frac{(-1)^2}{a}+\frac{(0)^2}{a}+\frac{(1)^2}{a}+\frac{(2)^2}{a}=1$$

Does that give you a push in the right direction?

Comment: Yes! So I got a = 10, and E(X) = 0?

Comment: I also got $a=10$. Considering the distribution is symmetric, and centered at $0$, that makes sense for the expected value.

Comment: What are your thoughts on my probability distribution for part b in the original post (updated)?

Comment: That seems right, yeah.

Comment: Would part c be 2? If so, there is actually a part d that says use the actual formula instead of the answer from part b and I'm not getting the same answers...

Comment: Well, the expected value of $Z$ is certainly $2$. The formula I usually use for variance is $E(X^2)-E(X)^2$. That seems to be $3.4$, if I'm not making an error.

Comment: @Hello Your answer for (b) is not *quite* right, so the answer for (c) is erraneous too.

Answer (score 0):

> a) a = 10, E(X) = 0

Yes. $
{~\\{P_X(x) =
\begin{cases} 0/a^2 & : & x=0 \\ 1/a^2 &:& x\in\{-1,1\} \\ 4/a^2 & : & x\in\{-2,2\}\\ 0 & : & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} }\\~\\ {\therefore ~a=10, \mathsf E(X)=0}}
$

---

> b) ${P(Z = z) = \begin{cases} 
>       \frac{1}{5} & z = 0 \\
>       \frac{2}{5} & z = 1,4 
>   \end{cases}}$

No, but close. Try again.

Having found $a=10$ and $\mathsf E(X)=0$ you know know that $Z=X^2$ and can find $P_Z(z)= P_X(+\surd z)+ P_X(-\surd z)$  since: $$
P_X(x) =
\begin{cases} 0 & : & x=0 \\ 1/10 &:& x\in\{-1,1\} \\ 4/10 & : & x\in\{-2,2\}\\ 0 & : & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore ...

---

c) Hint $\mathsf {Var}(X)=\mathsf E((X-\mathsf E(X))^2)$ and $Z=(X-\mathsf E(X))^2$ so...

Comment: I am a little confused by your hint for part b. For part c, I did notice that but did get led to the wrong answer since part b is incorrect. Is the probability distribution for part b supposed to include the constant a?

Comment: @Hello No. You already know $a=10$, and we have substituted that into the expression for $P_X(x)$ above.  You just need to evaluate $P_Z(z)$, which is $P_X(\surd z)+P_X(-\surd z)$, for $z\in\{0,1,4\}$.

Comment: So we have P(0) = 0, P(1) = (1/10) + (1/10), and P(2) = (4/10) + (4/10)?

Comment: Of course. @Hello

Comment: Is my updated edit to the original post correct?

Comment: Yes.  Did you find the variance okay using it?

Comment: Is it 0*0 + 1 * (2/10) + 2 * (8/10) = 1.8?

Comment: Given the answer to Problem 4.6 from [this link](https://robotics.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wlr/126SP07/HW/h4Sol.pdf), why would my answer not be similar to the "alt. b)" answer I provided above?

Comment: Because clearly: $\mathsf E(Z) = 0\cdot f_Z(0)+1\cdot f_Z(1)+4\cdot f_Z(4)$

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm sorry

Comment: The support for $Z$ is $\{0,1,4\}$ with the given probability mass function. So $0\cdot 0+1\cdot (2/10)+4\cdot(8/10) = 3.4$

Comment: Oh, okay. Is 1.8 the correct variance?